# What does 0xa55a mean in cga_init() in xv6 source code?

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

What does `0xa55a` mean here?

***Code:***

```
*cp = (uint16_t) 0xA55A;   
if (*cp != 0xA55A) {      /* 0xa55a means that? */
cp = (uint16_t*) (KERNBASE + MONO_BUF);
    addr_6845 = MONO_BASE;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code tests if `cp` is a writable address to determine whether the mode should be CGA or MONO. If writing does not work then we cannot use this part of memory. The thing (garbage) to be written should be arbitrary. It has **no special meaning** as far as I know.

Before this, the program saves the value at `cp` in `was` so the garbage won't poison the memory.

Comment: In the other words, 0xa55a can it be any value?

Comment: @AlexLiu Basically YES! I am not aware of any number you should avoid. Intuitively you would not choose something like 0. Just use a seemingly random number. I am happy to know if experiments show otherwise!

Comment: Yes, I change the value to 0x0101 and it works. Haha, Thank you very much for your answer.